# How do I stop random Hibernation/sleep? (Ubuntu Desktop 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu Desktop running 18.04 with sleep and hibernation turned off, no monitor/keyboard plugged in, been running now for several weeks with a few custom services perfectly fine.

This morning it was not responding via ssh, and the services were not talking to a cloud application.

I had to restart the machine to get access to any logs. A custom service ran just half a second before this log, so the machine was still active. Some help how to stop this random sleep/hibernation would be great.

```
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.1230] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.1236] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.1253] device (enp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 06:54:00 home whoopsie[1025]: [06:54:00] offline
Feb 02 06:54:00 home gnome-shell[859]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Feb 02 06:54:00 home dbus-daemon[662]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.15' (uid=0 pid=709 comm="/usr/sbin/Network
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.1615] device (enp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 06:54:00 home avahi-daemon[684]: Withdrawing address record for xxx on enp1s0.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home avahi-daemon[684]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp1s0.IPv6 with address xxx.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home avahi-daemon[684]: Interface enp1s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.1970] dhcp4 (enp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 968
Feb 02 06:54:00 home dbus-daemon[662]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.1971] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed bound -> done
Feb 02 06:54:00 home systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home nm-dispatcher[24574]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Feb 02 06:54:00 home avahi-daemon[684]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.4.44 on enp1s0.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home nm-dispatcher[24574]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Feb 02 06:54:00 home avahi-daemon[684]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp1s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.4.44.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home avahi-daemon[684]: Interface enp1s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1612248840.2066] device (enp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 06:54:00 home kernel: r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Down
Feb 02 06:54:00 home nm-dispatcher[24574]: req:2 'down' [enp1s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Feb 02 06:54:00 home nm-dispatcher[24574]: req:2 'down' [enp1s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Feb 02 06:54:00 home systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 02 06:54:00 home systemd[1]: Starting Hybrid Suspend+Hibernate...
Feb 02 06:54:00 home kernel: PM: Image not found (code -22)
Feb 02 06:54:00 home systemd-sleep[24587]: Suspending system...
Feb 02 06:54:00 home kernel: PM: hibernation entry
```

This was also the power setting during this time

```
:/home/me# su - gdm -s /bin/bash
:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type
'nothing'
:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
'nothing'
:~$ dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type
'nothing'
:~$ dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
0
:~$ dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout
1200
```

Comment: How often does it happen? Anything you changed recently? It sounds a bit like a one-time occurrence.

Comment: This is the first time i;ve seen the log, but i ive had it stop several times before like this. Before it stopped the one of the applications reported it had been on for 10866mins (roughly 7.5 days)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find the cause why these sleep/hibernation statuses are induced, you may just disable them altogether (it is a 24/7 server anyway).

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: Thanks @Fiximan, Yeah its a 25/7 machine that doesnt need any sleep function. I thought i had disabled all forms of sleep in the settings but clearly not. Will see if this solves my issue.

Comment: I got a ODROID XU4 doing this on Ubuntu 20.04 and masking didn't stop it disconnecting the network every 20 minutes.  Bout to just go back to 18.04 but this has been a bit of a time vamp.